# How to match operator-separated strings in Sublime Package Development YAML tmlanguage

Tags: regex, string, sublimetext2, yaml, tmlanguage

I am making a syntax definition for a custom-made language in sublime text 2 using PackageDevelopment's *.YAML-tmLanguage*. For now I want my syntax to identify strings to non strings.

sample line of code:

```
string name = "Chuck Norris";
string message = "I am " + name + ", don't mess with a \"ROCKSTAR\"!";
```

my pattern for double quoted string:

```
- comment: strings in double quotes
  match: (".+")
  captures:
    '1': {name: string.quoted.double.me}
```

what the pattern captures:

string name = `"Chuck Norris"`;
string message = `"I am " + name + ", don't mess with a "ROCKSTAR"!"`;

line 1 above is correct but line 2 seems to capture all.

**what I want is:**

string name = `"Chuck Norris"`;
string message = `"I am "` + name + `", don't mess with a "ROCKSTAR"!"`;

Comment: make it lazy using `.+?`..check :- https://regex101.com/r/pC5wN5/1

Comment: @rock321987, already tried that solution.. but it doesn't work

Comment: `[^"]+` should also work(if there is no nested `"` inside the string)

Comment: @rock321987 checked the link.. Tried it also on sublime PackageDev and voila! it worked!

Comment: I thought you will tell `voila! it didn't worked! `

Comment: Wait, there is a YAML tm grammar file. It works alright as is now.  http://imgur.com/U7Yot9V

Comment: @rock321987, truly your a **ROCKSTAR** !! :)

Comment: @catzilla: rock's suggestion won't work if you have `string mes = "I am a \"rock\" start.";`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you are right.. it seems that there are limitations.. I should update my question..

Comment: What about raw string literals spanning across multiple lines? Do you handle them already (there must be a separate block for them, I believe).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have not considered that yet, but it seems that it would pose a valid threat on my string matching.

Comment: Already told that it won't work for it..modification is needed for that

Comment: Well, putting raw string literals aside, try `"[^\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`. The problem is only when you have multiple lines since the rules only work per line only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have tried your suggestion but it seems that YAML parsing did not produce the expected result.

Comment: Maybe because you must double backslashes?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, hmmm.. didnt work yet.. I have tried it here https://regex101.com/r/pC5wN5/1

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/pC5wN5/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, tried it and yup.. it worked perfectly.. you are also a **ROCKSTAR**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a good implementation on how to match operator-separated strings and also to match double quoted strings and some additional functionalities using YAML.

@Wiktor Stribiżewv's answer also fulfills the question but I found a good implementation for this:

```
- comment: strings in double quotes
  name: string.quoted.double.hit
  begin: \"
  end: \"
  patterns:
  - comment: escape characters
    name: constant.character.escape.hit
    match: \\.

  - comment: special characters
    name: constant.character.hit
    match: \%.
```

this also matches escape characters like `\"`, `\n` and special characters `%s`, `%d`

Answer (score 1):

You need to match all characters that are not `"` and also combinations of `\`+anything in between the quotes.

Use

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pC5wN5/2)

It can also be written as `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"`. It is easier to read but is less efficient.

Comment: I found this answer correct and useful, however I also found a better implementation using YAML tmlanguage specifiers.

Comment: Then you can post. Actually, within begin/end, you can use nested rules, so you can declare the quotes as begin and end patterns and then  use a nesnested rule for an escaped entity.

Comment: yes, that is true.. what you said is exactly what I did. I used `begin` and `end`. and also used nesting.. :)